# Getting a 401 when making a HTTP POST request using CORS in Dart

Tags: dart, easypost

I am trying to build a small web app in Dart. The app calls the EasyPost web service, as illustrated with this curl call:

```
$ curl -X POST https://myuserid@api.easypost.com/v2/trackers
-d 'tracker[tracking_code]=EZ1000000001'
-d 'tracker[carrier]=FEDEX'
```

Here is the Dart code that I attempted to match this request:

```
// Configuration parameters
var url = "https://myuserid@api.easypost.com/v2/trackers";
var data = {
  'tracker[tracking_code]': '$packageNo',
  'tracker[carrier]': 'FEDEX'
 };

// Make the request
var request = new HttpRequest();
request
  ..open("POST", url, async: true)
  ..withCredentials = true
  ..onLoadEnd.listen((_) => print(request.responseText))
  ..send(data.toString());
```

When I run this in WebStorm the code fails when making the request with a CORS error:

```
POST https://api.easypost.com/v2/trackers 401 (Unauthorized)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.easypost.com/v2/trackers.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed
access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Isn't that supposed to be handled automatically? Or do I need to add those headers to the request myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The headers need to be added by the server, otherwise the client won't make the request. With a `POST` request the browser makes a preflight request to check the CORS headers. If they are not added by the server, the browser just doesn't make the actual `POST` request.

If the server doesn't add these headers it's probably not intended to be used this way.

There are some possible workarounds: http://usamadar.com/2012/06/24/getting-around-browsers-same-origin-policy-sop-with-proxies-script-injection-jsonp-and-cors/

Comment: I tried switching to the Postmaster API and now my code indeed works, so I think you are right that this service somehow doesn't properly support CORS. Thanks!